# How to calculate % of successful queries

Tags: bash, bc

I am trying to calculate what is the % of successful queries in apache log.
I have two commands:

```
cat access_log|cut -d' ' -f10|grep "2.."|wc -l
```

and

```
cat access_log|cut -d' ' -f10|wc -l
```

They return me the number of successful queries and total queries number. I want to calculate what is the % of successful requests using bash and if it is possible - it should be 1 line script. It suppose to output just the % number like - 50 or 12 without any additional info.

I tried to use bc with it but failed because of lack of knowledges. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $(( 100 * $( cut -d' ' -f10 access_log|grep "2.."|wc -l) / $(cut -d' ' -f10 access_log|wc -l) ))
```

Bash can only handle integers.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and only iterates through the logfile once:

```
awk '{if ((199 < $9) && ($9 < 300)) {SUMOK++} else {OTHER++}} END { printf "%d\n", ((SUMOK/NR)*100)}' access_log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Replace $9 with correct field number of status code.

```
awk '{if ($9 == 200)  no_of_200+=1 } END{ perc=(no_of_200/NR)*100; print perc}' access.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne'\|^\([^ ]*  *\)\{9\}2..|=;$=;$s|.*|2ksmzlm/p|'|dc
```

...works...

for example:

```
printf %s\\n 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 |
sed -ne'/1/=;$=;$s|.*|2ksmzlm/p|p'|dc
```

---

```
.20
```

...to show that `sed` matched the `1` pattern against 20% of its input lines.